# This is more a mutual

Tags: articles

Below is a certain dictionary explanations.

agree on : Two or more people have the same view about an issue. This is more a mutual. It suggests an equality in status.

Q: In the above sentence, I wonder whether the article 'a' is possible before adjective alone like in the above sentence,

Comment: which dictionary? maybe this can help us answer your question, thanks!

Comment: I can't find it now. I copied three years ago.

Comment: @Felix:  https://espanol.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070517125542AAVHrDo this might be the link, but I am not sure

Answer (score 1):

Your question is based on a typographic error.  The line should read

> This is more a mutual ***understanding***.